# WPF <WrapPanel> style background colour changes <Menu> colour - How to prevent this

Tags: wpf, xaml, app.xaml

I'm trying to apply styles to a WrapPanel in Visual Studio. The application is very simple, and just consists of a single Window with a 2 row Grid, with `<Menu>` in a `<Dockbar>` in the top row, and a `<WrapPanel>` in the bottom row. For some reason, when i set a background colour on the WrapPanel in `App.xaml` by adding:

```
<Style TargetType="WrapPanel">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"
</Style>
```

to `<Application.Resources>`, the background colour of my `<Menu>` changes to green as well when i start the application, despite not being in a WrapPanel. The designer preview doesn't show the green either, it only turns out to be green when running.

Adding an explicit blue background style for `<Menu>` in

```
<Style TargetType="Menu">
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue">
</Style>
```

makes the menu appear blue in the designer, but when i run it it's green again. I haven't made any edits to the background anywhere else, so i can't figure out why it's doing this.

Comment: `<Style TargetType="WrapPanel">` defines a default Style for all WrapPanels in your application. It also affects WrapPanels that are used by other elements, like Menus.

Comment: I haven't put a WrapPanel inside the Menu, do Menus contain a hidden WrapPanel somehow? Can't find a reference to that in the documentation.

Comment: Not you, but the framework devlopers. It is defined in the Menu's default Template. Add an `x:Key` to your WrapPanel Style and assign it explictly to all WrapPanels where you want to have it.